# Pacemaker Resource always stopped

Tags: linux, centos

I'm setting pacemaker for heartbeat seeing the doc

https://skcave.wordpress.com/2014/11/04/creating-high-availability-cluster-with-centos-7/

When I set the pacemaker as above, there is no problem.
But when I shutdown two node, strangely, resource always ***stop*** not start..

like

```
[root@restcent3 ~]# pcs status
Cluster name: hatest
WARNING: no stonith devices and stonith-enabled is not false
WARNING: corosync and pacemaker node names do not match (IPs used in setup?)
Last updated: Fri Jun  3 03:54:20 2016      Last change: Fri Jun  3 03:28:10 2016 by root via cibadmin on restcent3
Stack: corosync
Current DC: restcent2 (version 1.1.13-10.el7_2.2-44eb2dd) - partition with quorum
2 nodes and 1 resource configured

Online: [ restcent2 restcent3 ]

Full list of resources:

 virtual_ip7    (ocf::heartbeat:IPaddr2):   Stopped

PCSD Status:
  restcent3 (192.168.11.157): Online
  restcent2 (192.168.11.159): Online

Daemon Status:
  corosync: active/enabled
  pacemaker: active/enabled
  pcsd: active/enabled
```

Though, after two node rebooted, cluster state quite correct (as Active)

But I don't know why resource always becomes Stop..

So, repeating deleting and create same resource (changing resource id),
sometimes, it seems Started but, after rebooting the node which started,
it becomes UNCLEAN state after that, it becomes STOP though rest node is online.

And, now though I create resource. It's always stopped.

How can I solve this problem? And when resource is stopped, how can I start the resource?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the problem..

the problem happens because stonith-enable is true!

so after runing below command, the problem is gone!

> pcs property set stonith-enabled=false

Comment: Though the above-said property is set to false, I am facing this issue. any clues?

Comment: I've disabled STOINTH but still IPAddr2 resource is moving when my dead node comes to life, problem described here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57755212/pacemaker-corosync-vip-switches-when-node-is-brought-online